# Tomcat Run takes forever if database already stored so many data

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, struts2, runtime

I have this maven build with goals : tomcat:run , when i have clean database, it takes only 30 seconds to 1.5 minutes to run. But if i have already have many data stored on database it takes forever.

For information :
i use **struts2** and project builder **appfuse** framework.

This is my log if i already have stored so many data in my database :

```
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:08.765 [main] ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:08.918 [main] XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jan 13 10:14:08 ICT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:08.972 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-resources.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.121 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.266 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-service.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.413 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.772 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-struts.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.835 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.862 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:09.879 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.002 [main] XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security.xml]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.055 [main] SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.3.RELEASE
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.055 [main] SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.3.RELEASE
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.201 [main] HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser - Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.753 [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.754 [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [mail.properties]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.754 [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [hibernate.properties]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.769 [main] AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.857 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'userManagerTx' of type [class org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.860 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'userManagerSecurity' of type [class org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.862 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'managerTx' of type [class org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.876 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.method.MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.891 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.901 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:10.961 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:11.174 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:13.941 [main] HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@c69c38] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2015-01-13 10:14:14 INFO  ReflectionServiceFactoryBean:434 - Creating Service {http://impl.service.carnaval.gnv/}UserService from class gnv.carnaval.service.UserService
2015-01-13 10:14:14 INFO  ServerImpl:85 - Setting the server's publish address to be /UserService
2015-01-13 10:14:14 WARN  AnnotationUtils:172 - Method getUserByUsername in gnv.carnaval.service.UserService has no JAX-RS Path or HTTP Method annotations
2015-01-13 10:14:14 INFO  ServerImpl:85 - Setting the server's publish address to be /api
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:15.012 [main] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/images/**'], []
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:15.019 [main] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/styles/**'], []
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:15.022 [main] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/scripts/**'], []
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:15.026 [main] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/assets/**'], []
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:15.919 [main] DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@714f32ff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@69d3d77, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3d2e5305, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2c4c8ca4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@55a579b4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@62d94459, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@261661c2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@76c1b17, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4a6686cf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@111ca632]
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:15.963 [main] DefaultFilterChainValidator - Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
[INFO ] 2015-01-13 10:14:16.011 [main] ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7244 ms
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: You must have something in the init of your app (constructors of a service, @PostConstruct on a Bean, ...) that reads from the database. Try to locate it! You may activate the sql_requests in Hibernate to see which requests are made! I can't really help you more with the information we have!

Comment: The logs you've posted starts at `2015-01-13 10:14:08.765` and ends at `2015-01-13 10:14:16.011`. Doesn't seem like forever...

Comment: this is the wrong log, its the fast one. What happens for the slow one? It seems you are using hibernate? Try to enable the debug and trace log so you can see what queries are executed during startup.

Comment: @AleksandrM actually that's log is not finish, cause the finish one is end with this line :                                  `[INFO ] 2015-01-13 20:22:02.921 [main] ResponseOverrideFilter - Filter initialized. Response buffering is enabled
Jan 13, 2015 8:22:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8787
Jan 13, 2015 8:22:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8787`

Comment: @wemu yes, i am using hibernate, how can i enable that debug and trace? where can i find the configuration? I'm sorry, im new at this

Comment: look at the hibernate version and into the documentation. there are also tutorials available that may help: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/ - this page uses an older hibernate version but it includes the link to the hibernate log categories. There is also an option to add a JDBC logger to the project if the queries are not executed by hibernate: https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/